# Git repos in extra-deps

Tags: git, haskell, github, haskell-stack

What's the proper way of referencing a specific version of a `git` repository with `Stack`?

Stack complains about a parse error for the first field in `extra-deps` section of `stack.yaml`. Having based the snippet below on an example from the official Stack documentation, I'm not quite sure why it doesn't work.

```
# Dependency packages to be pulled from upstream that are not in the resolver
# (e.g., acme-missiles-0.3)
extra-deps:
- git: https://github.com/jwaldmann/moo
  commit: b429a7d371c0b268a4bb8dbea8044054aaf04cd5
- git: https://github.com/jwaldmann/monad-mersenne-random
  commit: d1f949fe60dc0c0cfbd310b339fe7fd5ecf4c5f5
- gray-code-0.3.1
#extra-deps: [gray-code-0.3.1]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking at documentation for the latest development version of stack.  The syntax you are using will be supported in stack 1.6 and newer, which will be released in a few days.

Note the disclaimer at the top of the documentation - https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/yaml_configuration.md

Whereas you should instead look at https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/

Answer (score 1):

See example in [this project](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-sl/blob/388ca8f147862710316709d2a095726901f4dcbc/stack.yaml#L31) which has a lot of external dependencies from *GitHub*.

Comment: Thank you. Do you happen to know why my example doesn't work? Has the support for adding git repos to `extra-deps` been removed?

Comment: I'd like to accept, but it's not a standalone answer, since it depends on a link.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake I'm not sure about support for `extra-deps`... But this should be done like this: you add dependency to your package and mark is as `extra-dep: true`. Because in Haskell build system when you depend on github repository you basically depend on local package. But `stack` handles downloading from GitHub for you automatically.

Comment: I think the issue stemmed from a malformed `packages` section, and possibly outdated `stack` documentation. Thanks for your help.